# I want to filter data according to m courseCode my i am unable to figure out how to do

Tags: javascript, node.js

this is my json data after converting this with res.json()

i tried to filter it on the basis of course code lets say its code : 301 my i am confused how to do that with javascript
because it is so much nested
this is the code i used

```
const filteredStudents = students.map((element) => {
       return {...element, course: element.course.some((subElement) => subElement.code === courseCode)}
     })
```

for this data

```
{
    "students": [
        {
            "_id": "643d28067ef4bb6091a0376a",
            "name": "Michael Johnson",
            "course": [
                {
                    "_id": "6434fcb866ddd5fafed57dd5",
                    "name": "Database Management Systems",
                    "code": "CS201",
                    "sessions": 15,
                    "__v": 0
                },
                {
                    "_id": "6434fcb866ddd5fafed57dd7",
                    "name": "Operating Systems",
                    "code": "CS401",
                    "sessions": 18,
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "_id": "643d28067ef4bb6091a0376b",
            "name": "Emily Brown",
            "course": [
                {
                    "_id": "6434fcb866ddd5fafed57dd5",
                    "name": "Database Management Systems",
                    "code": "CS201",
                    
                    "sessions": 15,
                    "__v": 0
                },
                {
                    "_id": "6434fcb866ddd5fafed57dd6",
                    "name": "Artificial Intelligence",
                    "code": "CS301",
                    
                    "sessions": 25,
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ]
        },
```

Comment: Which array are you trying to filter?  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: You should add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve] together with your expected output.

Comment: i want those students who have at this least one course code matching for eg i want student with  "code": "CS301", then i want index of Emily Brown

Comment: Do you mean `id` rather than `index`? What if Emily Brown isn't in the list of filtered data? @csAshish

Comment: then student does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a combination of [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const studentsArray = fromAPI.students;

const filteredArray = studentsArray.filter((currentStudent) => currentStudent.course.some(currentCourse => currentCourse.code === '301'))
```

Comment: They are two nested loops, it's not good for performance in particular for long lists: if you have access to the API it's probably better for the filter to be applied by the DB.